# JSLint how to allow `in` operator?

Tags: javascript, jslint

I'm trying to follow JSLint convention, but am facing a strange restriction in using `in` operator, as in `if (a in b) { ... }` context.

Is there any way to allow this particular operator? I can live with ++ being replaced by += 1, but there isn't any analogy to `in`, and by disallowing it, it makes probing for inherited properties together with own properties extremely cumbersome for absolutely no reason.

JSLint itself suggest using `hasOwnProperty` or compare to `undefined` - but both do the wrong thing (a property may exist, but have a value of `undefined`, a property may be declared on a prototype of the object in question).

The workaround is to loop through all properties of the object and compare them to the property in question, but this instantly converts and O(1) operation into O(n)...

Comment: How about using http://www.jshint.com/ ? It's less strict in such cases and has a ton of configuration options as well: http://www.jshint.com/docs/

Comment: https://github.com/daleharvey/jshint-mode might help... I don't use Emacs though, so sorry if I'm making silly suggestions :)

Comment: Could you post a little more of your code in context? Is `a` created on the fly?  I mean, obviously you can check the truthiness of `if (b.a) {`, but I'm assuming your `a` isn't known before that point in your code?

Comment: @wvxvw Sure. Just not real sure what you're running into that truthiness and/or `undefined ===` isn't buying you.  See [JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/rufwork/mUr95/1/); you're obviously running into something *not* in that fiddle. In any event, I'm glad JSHint seems to have worked, just curious as to what you were seeing.

Comment: Ah, you're serializing to JSON or similar.  That's an interesting use case I was overlooking; good call.  Probably worth [asking Crockford](https://plus.google.com/communities/104441363299760713736); he's very quick to respond, and, overlooking some (perhaps not undeservedly) terse replies, exceptionally helpful, often changing and publishing the JSLint code within minutes.

Answer (score 0):

For those using JSLint in other contexts, here are a few more potential solutions:

1. Write a utility function to localize use of the `in` operator to just that one function. Then exclude that one file from linting.
2. Use a patched version of JSLint (search for `'infix_in'` – I think commenting out the `warn()` call would work).
3. Run a script on the JSLint output to filter out errors related to operator `in`. In this case the string is unique so it should be easy to reliably filter out.

Btw, the other annoyance mentioned here – replacing `++` with `+= 1` – *can* be turned off. Just use the `plusplus: true` option.

Comment: Some other linting systems let you set a policy where `++`/`--` in a standalone line (e.g. `foo++;`) are ok but use inside of expressions - where it's most likely to be confusing - is disallowed (e.g. `x = (y++);`). I find that to be the nicest balance.